# css flex box and set height to 100% of children element but the children element stretch equal to screen height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have HTML like so

```
<div class="box-wrap">
    <div class="box">
        <h3>new tab h3</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <h3>new tab h3</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <h3>new tab h3</h3>
        <h3>new tab h3</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.box-1 {
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
}
.box-wrap {
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.box {
    background: yellow;
}
```

There is really weird thing happened
when I set height of .box class to height: 100%, it gonna stretch equal to screen height(HTML on my pc). but in codepen, it is not, the box only stretch the height equal to the height of another box, if another box is higher.

I really want my css in my HTML file to have the same behaviour in codepen
Can anyone know the problem or what causes this problem? Thanks
here is the codepen link: https://codepen.io/kqt/pen/oqKXxR

Comment: body,html {heght:100%}

Comment: I tried, but its not work

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple container elements stacked on top of each other in that codepen so I'm not sure exactly which you're having trouble with, but it seems like you were talking about the second one. If so, Temani Afif is right, you need to set 100% height on the body & html elements, but also every parent div down to the level of your flex container if you are trying to get that one to be the height of the screen. You also have an extra div wrapped around the whole thing with no css class on it, so if that really needs to be in there then it's also going to need the 100% height, but you can select it with body > div like so:

```
html,
body, 
body > div,
.container,
.box-container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XqbGpV

Comment: Thanks, but it's actually not what i meant. As you can see in codepen. If I set .swiper-slide {height: auto} and .box-1 {height: 100%} all .box-1 will have the same height. But when I do that in my local HTML file these .box-1 have the height equal to window height, not the heighest .box-1